# Datagridview DataView CellDoubleClick

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I´ve  a Datagridview. When I filter the Datagridview with a Dataview Rowfilter, the Datagridview CellDoubleClick Event not fires.

I´am sorry i have no idea to solve this.

```
DataView dv = new DataView(sourcedata);
        dv.RowFilter = "UserID LIKE 'TEST'";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

THX

Comment: Are you sure the event is wired up properly? Have you put a breakpoint in the first line of the event to see if it is getting hit?

Comment: Did u double click any cell after applying RowFilter?

Comment: Thx for the hint i found my Problem
if (e.RowIndex > 0)
change to
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)